# As epsilon decays, rewards gets worse during exploitation than exploration

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow, q-learning

I am currently trying to write learning agent from the "[Human Level Control in DRL](http://web.stanford.edu/class/psych209/Readings/MnihEtAlHassibis15NatureControlDeepRL.pdf)" Paper in Tensorflow 2.0. I've copied the recommended hyperparameters and picked the easiest environment possible. There has to be an error in my model because the rewards decrease the more epsilon decreases.

My model is identical to the one described in the paper (at least, I think it is).

```
def build_model(self, agent_history_length):
        # 4 greyscaled 84*84 images as an input
        inputs = keras.Input(shape=(agent_history_length, 84, 84))
        l1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(
            filters=32,
            kernel_size=(8, 8),
            strides=(4, 4),
            activation=keras.activations.relu,
            name="cnn_1",
            padding="same",
        )(inputs)
        l2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(
            filters=64,
            kernel_size=(4, 4),
            strides=(2, 2),
            activation=keras.activations.relu,
            name="cnn_2",
            padding="same",
        )(l1)
        l3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(
            filters=64,
            kernel_size=(3, 3),
            # stride=(1, 1),
            activation=keras.activations.relu,
            name="cnn_3",
            padding="same",
        )(l2)
        flatten = keras.layers.Flatten()(l3)
        l4 = keras.layers.Dense(
            512,
            activation=keras.activations.relu,
            name="dense_1"
        )(flatten)
        # for every action, there is an output
        outputs = keras.layers.Dense(
            self.num_actions,
            activation=keras.activations.relu,
            name="output"
        )(l4)
        optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=self.learning_rate, rho=.99, momentum=.95)
        model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
        self.model = model
        # use rmsprop (as used in Human-level control through deep 
        # reinforcement learning)
        self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
```

My training function should be the same as described in the paper too.

```
def learn(self):
        # retrieve 32 samples
        s, a, r, s_, d = self.experience_memory.pop()
        if s is None:
            return

        q_vals = self.network.model.predict(s)

        # retrieve the next expected maximum reward (from target network)
        q_vals_next = self.target_network.model.predict(s_)

        # y_values
        q_target = q_vals_next.copy()

        batch_index = [x for x in range(batch_size)]

        # bellman equation
        q_target[batch_index, a] = r + gamma * np.max(q_vals_next) * (1-d)

        self.network.model.fit(s, q_target, verbose=0)

        # update the target network every 10 episodes
        if self.current_step % (episode_steps * 10) == 0:
            self.target_network.model.set_weights(self.network.model.get_weights())
```

Something is off and I can't find the cause. I'd be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: what's epsilon? doesn't show up in any of your code

Comment: @shimao I didn't think that it would be relevant. Epsilon starts with 1.0 and deteriorates to 0.1 over a period of 1mio steps.

Comment: epsilon is just a greek letter. im asking, in the context of your problem, what does this parameter *do*?

Comment: @shimao I'm sorry. It's the exploration rate for the agent to take random actions. 1.0 means it will very likely take a random action. 0.1 means that ~(1 in 10) actions will be random.

Comment: This likely is not affecting your particular issue, but so noticed that your final layer has ReLU activation. The paper states it should be linear, which is intuitive, because otherwise your model would never be allowed to predict negative reward, which means it would never train properly. As per the rest, you should probably provide a reproducible example in full so we can ensure there are no accidental bugs in your code.